# What are the differences in SSH rights?

Tags: linux, ssh

If I go to the server through SSH, only then read the environment variables, then they are read:

```
ssh 192.bla.bla.bla
echo $MY_VAR
```

If I read them with one command, then a error:

```
ssh 192.bla.bla.bla -t 'echo $MY_VAR'
```

Although the `whoami` comand both cases suggests that the user is the same.

Why does the second option not work?

Comment: What error? The difference is probably due to the fact that `sshd` will start a login shell in the first case, but a non-login shell to run `echo $MY_VAR` in the second.

Comment: Ideally it should work , Without pasting error can not comment on it .
Could be the reason $MY_VAR declaring in your profile , it will only execute in case of a interactive login .

Comment: I want it to work with the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for the tip.
The following command works:

```
ssh 192.bla.bla.bla 'source /etc/profile; source ~/.profile; echo $MY_VAR'
```